# Matching/comparing graph trends in JAVA

Tags: java, graph, design-patterns, matching

Is there any open-source library in Java for comparing the trends of two given graphs?  I want to compare two graphs and determine how similar the trends are.

Comment: You might get better answers here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague. How are your graphs defined? by a function or by data points? What do you mean by trends? Do you mean actually the parameters of a certain interpolation?

http://commons.apache.org/math/

Take a look at apache math above, but i requires you to have some basic understanding of the math and stats theories, and locate the correct function you want to use in their javadocs.